# Как использовать видеоплеер, что б файл нельзя было скачать?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asp.net-core

Подскажите пожалуйста пример для сервера и для браузера, как создать видеопросмотр, защищённый от скачивания для защиты авторских прав?
Как я понял - нужно и на сервере и на клиенте писать, что б была зашифрованная буферизация и скачивание фрагментами?
Скрин и запись экрана не считаю.  Ясное дело, кто очень хочет- скачает, но хочется процесс усложнить, что б отсеять первый эшелон, желающих скачать.

Comment: Никак, это не возможно. Вы можете усложнить процесс скачивания, но полностью защититься не сможете. Еще есть [вот такое](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2).

Comment: @aepot ну понятное дело, что от записи экрана я не защищу, но всё -же что б обычного пользователя(не программиста) исключить от возможности скачивания?

Comment: Я уже привел ссылку выше, как это делают взрослые видео-стриминговые сервисы. Но я не про запись экрана, я именно про скачивание. Что бы вы там не придумали, как бы не перепутывали байты, у вас всегда есть видеоплеер, который это все распутывает, и вот из него и можно забрать поток. JS - даже обфусцированный, читается не так сложно как хотелось бы, а отладчики в браузерах божественные. Инструментов свести на нет все ваши старания - полно, знаний каких-то космических для этого тоже не требуется. Поэтому DRM, он хотя-бы в стандартных популярных браузерах дает защиту, лучше всего остального.

Comment: Обычные пользователи идут в гугл, видят не просто даже описания "как скачать" -- но десятки готовых сайтов, которые скачают, разнообразные плагины под популярные браузеры, десктопные программы под основные ОС... Вы так уверены, что доставите неприятность пользователю? Он даже не заметит, что там защита уровня "только для программистов".